# Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'XXX' cannot be found on null

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I only get the error in the console of the IDE, the webpage looks Great.
I tried using the th:if to look for null, but that didn't get rid of the issue.
And the title is never null, so I don't know why I'm getting the error, again only in the console, the webpage, including the title displays fine.
This is my first question on this website, I review code here all the time and find so many great answers, I thought why not try and get some help.  I've spent so much time on this one and can't seem to find anyone else with the same issue.

Not enough room to paste the entire stack trace.  But also receive this cause of error:

Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "post.title" (template: "post/view" - line 19, col 17)

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:replace="main :: head"></head>



<!--<html lang="en"-->
<!--html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:layout:decorate="layouts/main.html">-->

<div th:replace="main :: main">&nbsp;</div>
<body>


    <article style="padding:20px">
        <header>
             <h2 th:text="${post.title}">title</h2>
             <p th:text="${#calendars.format(post.postedOn,'M/dd/yyyy hh:mm a')}">postedOn</p>
        </header>
        <section th:utext="${post.body}">
            body
        </section>
        <footer>
            <address>
                Posted By <a th:href="|mailto:${post.author.email}|"> <span th:text="|${post.author.firstName} ${post.author.lastName}|">author</span></a>
            </address>
        </footer>
        <hr/>
    </article>

</div>
    <div th:replace="main :: bottom">&nbsp;</div>

</body>
</html>

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/posts")
public class PostController {
    private static final Logger logger =   LoggerFactory.getLogger(PostController.class);

    private PostService postService;

    @Autowired
    public PostController(PostService postService){
        this.postService = postService;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/list")
    public String listPosts(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("posts", postService.list());
        return "post/list";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/view/{slug}")
    public String view(@PathVariable(value="slug") String slug, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("post", postService.getBySlug(slug));
        return "post/view";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/byAuthor/{id}")
    public String byAuthor(@PathVariable(value="id") Long id, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("posts", postService.listByAuthor(id));
        return "post/list";
    }


}
```

Comment: If the code works fine when you run it, and you're just seeing some warning in your IDE, you may need to give details on what IDE it is and how you're running it.

Comment: I'm using intelliJ and just choosing the run option.

Comment: Can you share your Java code?

Comment: shared the controller and service class above

Comment: The issue seems to be with this statement:  <head th:replace="main :: head"></head>  This statement works in all my other html without causing a problem.  The other replace statement in this html work fine, it's just this one.  I copied the code that is in the head section directly into this html file rather than using the replace and it solved the problem.  I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with this statement:  This statement works in all my other html without causing a problem. The other replace statements in this html work fine, it's just this one. I copied the code that is in the head section directly into this html file rather than using the replace and it solved the problem. I have no idea why. –